# The angularjs tab don't switch?

Tags: angularjs, tabs

why the tab don't switch?  when i click the tab 2 or other,it seems to do nothing.

```
    <div class="container">
    <h1>Bootstrap AngularJS Tabs</h1>
    <div ng-app="">
    <div ng-init="names = [{name:'one'}, {name:'two'}, {name:'three'}, {name:'four'}, {name:'five'}]">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li ng-repeat="name in names" ng-class="{active: $index == 0}">
        <a href="#tab{{$index + 1}}" data-toggle="tab">Tab {{$index + 1}}</a>
                    </li>
            </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="tab{{$index + 1}}" ng-repeat="name in names" ng-class="{active: $index == 0}">
        <span>{{$index + 1}}</span><span>{{$index+2}}</span>
    </div>
            </div>

            </div>
            </div>
    </div><!--/container-->
    <script src="./angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Where is your JS script ?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're always setting the first tab to active by doing `ng-class="{active: $index == 0}"`. You need to compare `$index` to a property on the scope which you change when the user clicks on the tab header (by combining both the `href` on your anchor, and an `ng-click`). Something like this simplified version: http://jsbin.com/tesosisi/1/edit

That example sets `$scope.names.activeIndex = 0;` in the controller, but you'd want to inspect the current location hash to see which tab should be active from the start.